# Replacing broken bathroom fan - mounted in the loft (UK)

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan, uk

I have a small bathroom (8.5m^3) with a (now broken) ceiling mounted, extractor fan. The fan itself is enclosed in a plastic box mounted to a joist in the loft so the bottom face is flush with the ceiling. In the loft, the fan is attached to an insulated 4” flexible duct which covers around 2 meters before venting outside.

I’ve been looking in the usual places (Screwfix, B&Q, Wickes etc) for a replacement, but I’m not seeing anything that looks similar (i.e. mounted in a box which can go in the loft). Everything I’m seeing just has the 4” pipe at the rear, so I’d have to fill the old hole back in then drill a new 4” hole and somehow suspend the fan with just plasterboard – I know this isn’t the right approach, but I’m not seeing any other options.

Am I missing something or searching for the wrong thing? Do companies still sell these or has technology moved on?

[image: Fan with cover]
[image: Cover removed]

Comment: "Am I missing something..."   Yes, you're missing a picture so we can see what you've got.

Comment: I've added a couple of pictures to make it clearer.

Comment: My recommendation would be to contact the manufacturer.  Many US fan companies make (basically drop in) replacement units for when the fan motor finally craps out.

Comment: I've already tried. They don't make this model anymore.

Comment: At least for US fans common in recent decades, many online sites carry replacement motors. If your fan can be removed from the ceiling and disassembled, you may be able to source a replacement motor even if your current unit is not available as a whole unit replacement. The motor inside would be labeled according to voltage, current, power etc so you could then search for a match.

Comment: Is the issue that you need a fan with the exhaust pointing up rather than coming out the side?

Comment: @GrahamEvans do you have access above, or is there a living space there?

Comment: I have good access to the loft above. The issue is I can't find a fan which comes with a box that I can mount above a plasterboard ceiling and screw onto a joist to take the weight. I've seen plenty of (US based) youtube videos showing people replacing a similar fan with one from Lowes / Home Depot etc, but UK stores dont seem to stock anything that looks familiar. Or, as I suspect, I'm searching using the wrong terms.

Comment: See the offerings on here - https://www.extractorfanworld.co.uk/bathroom-fans-8-c.asp [scroll way down] - you could get an inline fan, which *will* fix to the joist, then run ducting from the vent & again to the outside. Available singly or as kits with vent & ducting.